# An attribute of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, attributes, decorator

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)

def count(f):
    def counted(*args):
        counted.call_count += 1 
        return f(*args)
    counted.call_count = 0
    return counted

>>> fib = count(fib)
>>> fib(5)
5
>>> fib.call_count
15
>>> counted.call_count
NameError
```

I understand that `fib` is now actually `counted`. However, I cannot figure out why, when I want to call `counted.call_count`, I have to call `fib.call_count`.

I think that `counted` is an instance of the class `Function`. But what does `counted.call_count` exactly mean?

More specifically, I do not understand an attribute defined outside the code `class ****:`. In that case defining an attribute is like `self.call_count` is clearer, because I can understand `self` to refer to the instance. In my example, it seems that `counted` in `counted.call_count` is just like `self` in `self.call_count`, but is it?

Comment: `counted.call_count` wouldn't just show "Error". It would show NameError, telling you that `counted` is not defined in the current scope.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Ok, thanks! But I think that's not the point... What I want to know is why I have to call "fib.call_count",  as I added just know. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the `counted` function isn't called `counted` in your main program code, it's called `fib`. (`count` returns `counted`, which you bind to `fib` with an assignment), so that's the name you should use.

Your reliance on the decorated function name is a little tenuous. You will observe that you rely on that name. If you change the calling code to read

```
fibfun = count(fib)
fibfun(5)
fibfun.call_count
```

you will see it only counts the outer call.

You are in fact writing a decorator, though you may not know it. A more conventional way to write this might be

```
def count(f):
    def counted(*args):
        counted.call_count += 1 
        return f(*args)
    counted.call_count = 0
    return counted

@count
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
```

There's then no need to wrap the function manually (the decorator syntax simply does the call for you), and you can just write

```
>>> fib(5)
5
>>> fib.call_count
15
```

The problem is that you can only call this decorated function once, unless you take into account that the count continues to accumulate as further calls are made:

```
>>> fib(5)
5
>>> fib.call_count
30
```

This may be acceptable. Otherwise, further complexity may be required.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about how the python interpreter works under the hood may help you understand what's going on here. When source code is passed through the lexer, and turned into bytecode we can see references to "load" and "store" commands indicating that the interpreter works primarily as a stack based machine:

```
>>> dis.dis(count)
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (counted)
              2 LOAD_CLOSURE             1 (f)
              4 BUILD_TUPLE              2
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object counted at 0x00000193D034C8A0, file "<ipython-input-2-a31b910d61de>", line 2>)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 ('count.<locals>.counted')
             10 MAKE_FUNCTION            8
             12 STORE_DEREF              0 (counted)

  5          14 LOAD_CONST               3 (0)
             16 LOAD_DEREF               0 (counted)
             18 STORE_ATTR               0 (call_count)

  6          20 LOAD_DEREF               0 (counted)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

We can also see that the `call_count` attribute is bound to the new code object that is created, but the name: `counted` is explicitly de-referenced as it is no longer in scope and only the code object is returned.